# Store and load media from filesystem to electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, html5-video

I have an application which is build in react and electron. It is used to capture images and videos from webcam.
Now I want to add a functionality to store those images and videos into the folder or into local db of chrome and also I want to reload those images and video when application restart.
How can I achieve this task ?
I have images and video as in variables in frontend so I can do the localdb stuff but how can I achieve file based storage?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Reading/writing files isn't that difficult so i assume you've tried something.

Comment: I have tried `fs` but don't know how to store videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how you can do is, you can store photos or videos on a local storage folder like app data and then just access it using the path. you can store videos in app data as `app.getPath('')`.it's simple as that. let me know if you haven't done yet